# Application Insights Query Issue

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I want to query AI to find all trace entries where the requests table has success == false.  The results should be all the trace entries that pertain to the InovationsId that had a failure.  I tried this query and it is failing.  Both the traces and the requests table have a customDimensions['InvocationId'] field that is the link that I want to use.

I tried these queries and I get a syntax error

```
    traces
    | join (requests | where success == false) on customDimensions['InvocationId']

    traces
    | join (requests | where success == false) on $left.customDimensions['InvocationId'] == 
    $right.customDimensions['InvocationId']

    traces
    | join (requests | where success == false) on traces.customDimensions['InvocationId'] == requests.customDimensions['InvocationId']
```

This is the query results message I get:

*join: Invalid entities used as join attributes. When using equality expressions, entities should be used by specifying its source $left or $right.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the `customDimensions['InvocationId']` is dynamic type, you should convert it to string type by using `tostring()` method.

Sample as below:

```
traces
| extend aa=tostring(customDimensions['InvocationId'])
| join (
       requests 
       | where success == false
       | extend aa=tostring(customDimensions['InvocationId'])
) on aa
```